# desarrollar una función que reciba como parámetro el employee_id y retorne el salary

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy tomando como ejemplo la base de datos de oracle hr
debo Validar que el empleado exista, en caso de que el usuario no exista retornar un error diga
“ESTE EMPLEADO NO PERTENECE A LA EMPRESA"

```
create or replace function empleado(p_idempleado in number)
return number
is

v_salary number;
begin

select salary
into v_salary
from employees
where employee_id = p_idempleado;
return v_salary;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Este empleado no pertenece a la compañia');
 
end;
```

No Me funciona cuando le paso un employee_id que no este en la tabla employees ejemplo este 1000 no existe

```
set serveroutput on;
declare

v_id number :=1000;
salario number;
begin
salario:=empleado(v_id);
dbms_output.put_line(salario);

end;
```

me devuelve este error

```
Informe de error -
ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value
ORA-06512: at "HR.EMPLEADO", line 20
ORA-06512: at line 6
06503. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Function returned without value"
*Cause:    A call to PL/SQL function completed, but no RETURN statement was
           executed.
*Action:   Rewrite PL/SQL function, making sure that it always returns
           a value of a proper type.
```

Comment: la variabel esta undefined por ende no retornara nada la solucion mas simple es asignarle un valor por defecto como 0

Comment: No entiendo en que parte, la verdad soy muy nueva en esto, pero necesito que si le paso un employee_id que no exista en la base de datos me debe de retornar el mensaje que pase en la exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que has creado, como todas las funciones requiere que devuelva un valor.

En tu caso cuando introduces un empleado que no existe intenta hacer ésto

```sql
select salary
into v_salary
from employees
where employee_id = p_idempleado;
```

Como falla, no continúa y no va al return de la línea siguiente sino que salta a la parte de la excepción.

Se podría resolver del siguiente modo: En la parte de la excepción lanzar un return de un valor que te indique que algo ha fallado:

```sql
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Este empleado no pertenece a la compañia');
 return -1000;
end;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, con esto ya  me funciono.